# What do you call the part of a novel that is not dialog?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Many novels consist of dialog - and the other part, the part that is not dialog. What do you call the part of a novel that is not dialog?

Comment: For what it's worth, dialogue isn't necessary in a novel and 'narrative'&mdash;despite being the correct answer for what you're looking for&mdash;can also be understood as meaning the *entire* account, dialogue and all.

Comment: Thanks, @lly, I rephrased the question to take into account that not all novels have dialog.

Comment: @lly For some reason, HTML character entities work in questions and answers, but not in comments.

Comment: @lly use `alt 0150` : "–" , and `alt 0151` : "—"

Comment: @Mazura Those don't work for people without a keypad. The coders here should just support the standard HTML code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the most general term is **narrative**:

> 1 A spoken or written account of connected events; a story.
>
> ‘*a gripping narrative*’
>
> 1.1 [mass noun] The narrated part of a literary work, as distinct from dialogue.
>
> ‘*the dialogue and the narrative suffer from awkward syntax*’

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/narrative)

Narrative includes *exposition*, which describes events that take place, and *description*, which describes people and places.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking 'narration' but that is better restricted to narratives where the narrator's voice is more pronounced. This is probably understood more generally.

Comment: I think narration and narrative are quite different things.

Comment: Can be. Which is what I just said, yes.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread/misunderstood your comment

Answer (score -7):

In a play this sort of material would usually be called **stage directions**, which might convey your intended meaning, depending on the audience.

Comment: Okay? This question is about novels.

Comment: Although it doesn't address the question asked, I think this is an insightful comment.

Comment: @user323578 Okay? Answers are for answering the question that was asked. Everything else should go in a comment.